# how to get UIImage from GPUImageView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

I want to get UIImage from GPUImageView.

I used tried below code to type cast but it is crashing and getting below error

-[GPUImageView image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1214e700

```
UIImageView *filterImageView=(UIImageView *)self.videoCamera.gpuImageView; //gpuimageview

    self.myImage = filterImageView.image;
```

I also referred below link [Getting UIImage from GPUImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950602/how-can-i-get-uiimage-from-gpuimageview)

But my requirement is different then they approached using GPUImageFilter

Any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A GPUImageView is not a subclass of UIImageView, so you can't cast it as such. There's no `image` property on that class.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the manual. You don't get the image from the GPUImageView. What you should do instead is use the capture functionality:

If you don't want to use a filter, you can just use an empty one, that does not alter the image.

```
[stillCamera capturePhotoProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error){
NSData *dataForPNGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(processedImage, 0.8);

}];
```